# Exception thrown when reading meta data from .tif file using c# and metadata extractor

Tags: c#, metadata-extractor

I am trying to read the metadata from a .tif file using the Metadata Extractor dll and I keep getting a FileIsNotFoundException. It works fine when I try the same code using a .jpeg file.

```
FileStream OriginalFile = new FileStream(FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
IEnumerable<MetadataExtractor.Directory> directories = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(OriginalFile);
foreach (var directory in directories)
    foreach (var tag in directory.Tags)
        Console.WriteLine($"{directory.Name} - {tag.Name} = {tag.Description}");
```

**Edit**: I re-installed the package and now have the XmpCore.dll inside the packages folder of my project but I still see the same exception as before. Works fine for .jpeg and .psd files.

[Exception thrown when trying open a .tiff image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCDxh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the exception by changing the Copy Local property to True for XmpCore under References in the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

FileNotFoundException means that your FullPath doesn't contain a file that's actually on disk.

Try adding:

```
Console.WriteLine(FullPath);
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(FullPath));
```

Also double check between .tif and .tiff.

**EDIT** Your screenshot shows the missing file is `XmpCore.dll`. When you added the NuGet reference to `MetadataExtractor`, you should also have picked up `XmpCore`.

Here's an example of `packages.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="MetadataExtractor" version="1.5.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="SharpZipLib" version="0.86.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="XmpCore" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Ensure you also have the relevant project references.

After building a new .NET 4.5 console project with the above `packages.config`, the `bin/Debug` folder looked like this:

[image]

And the contents of the `packages` folder:

[image]

Comment: I have already checked using `File.Exists` and it returns True.

Comment: Ah, ok. It cannot find XmpCore.dll. I suggest using NuGet to use the library, which will bring down the dependency on XmpCore.

Comment: I installed the Metadata Extractor using the package manager as per the instructions on NuGet

Comment: Is XmpCore.dll in the folder you are running from?

Comment: I dont see it next to the .exe file. I also dont see it in packages.

Comment: I just tried creating a new project with .NET 4.5 and MetadataExtractor 1.5.3, and it worked fine. Were there any errors in your package manager logs?

Comment: No the package install was successful with no errors.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. What framework/platform are you targetting?

Comment: The only difference I see in packages.config is `targetFramework="net461"`. Everything else matches.

Comment: What's in the `packages` folder? See my screenshot.

Comment: The Package folder contents also match.

Comment: I just created a net461 test project and it also worked. Sorry but I cannot tell what's going on with your environment, but I'm reasonably sure it's not a problem with metadata extractor.

Comment: I cleared out my debug folder and did another build and it does not have the XmpCore.dll file or the XmpCore.xml file in it. It has the other references correctly. When I try doing a `using XmpCore;` in my code it just says using that the directive is unnecessary.

Comment: I still don't see any of the schema metadata getting listed in the output.